# Java UI application: slow CPU growth

Tags: java, garbage-collection, profiling, cpu-usage, memory-profiling

I want to understand: is it a normal situation that CPU usage of the working java UI application is growing slowly (started from <= 1.5%, after 48 hours: <= 10%). I don't see memory leaks during the heapdump investigations.

Although, if I perform gc (using jvisualvm) and look at deltas (sample memory part), such classes as WeakReference, WeakListenerImpl are still growing (slowly).

Also, the problem is that major garbage collection occurs too often (practically every second), however at first few hours the situation was normal.

What could be the reason of a such application behavior?

JVM:
-Xms128m
-Xmx256m

GC:
default for jdk 1.8

Thank you in advance!

[image: jvisualvm]
[image: jvisualvm2]

Comment: "garbage collections occur too often"? Is there too much garbage?

Comment: No, my mistake.

Comment: (i.e., do your program create too many unused objects that need to be garbage collected?) And what mistake?

Comment: Possibly, as the program works under the pressure (often restarts of some components). However, the same situation was in first hours too. Although, minor gc occurs really often, but major gc occurs rarely.

Comment: what is your jvm? what are your xmx, xms, gc parameters (default or custom)? also describe the type of app: web, standalone, proxy...

Comment: See question updates.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, the problem is that major garbage collection occurs too often (practically every second), however at first few hours the situation was normal.

Consider increasing the max heap size (`Xmx`) to give the GCs more breathing room.

> Although, if I perform gc (using jvisualvm) and look at deltas (sample memory part), such classes as WeakReference, WeakListenerImpl are still growing (slowly).

There are two possibilities, either weak references themselves get cleared but the reference objects are not dequeued from a referencequeue (this would usually result in a very slow leak over time) or something is holding a strong reference to the objects.

You should take a heap dump and inspect what keeps the accumulating objects reachable from GC roots.